# Azure CosmosDB to .NET DataSet

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I have an exsistant application that uses a hard-typed dataset with about 10 different Tables. When the App Starts it fills the whole DataSet and then Saves it back when exiting, currently I have implemented it to support SqlCe as well as XML Storage types.

I would like to do the same with CosmosDB without having to modify the Dataset in any way, just be able to Save it to Cosmos and then Load it back.

App is currently using VB.net but I have no problems using C# for these classes so ideas can be in either language, I know C# is widely used :)

Comment: Visual Studio using entity will automatically read a database and create the classes (DataSet/DataTable) which maps the database to the c# application.  See following : https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/dotnet/net-framework/using-entity-framework-with-an-existing-database-data-access/

Comment: But i already have my own DataSet and I need to keep using it so i dont have to change any code, I need a way to fill my existant dataset and save it.

Comment: The you need to create a mapping file to map the entity classes (database tables) against your dataset.  Or add attributes to your classes.  I not sure which.  I would run a test and create a new project and create the classes from the link I provided.  Then compare your classes against the new classes to see the differences.

Comment: I see, that sounds silly imho, the DataSet is already there, there should be an easy way to just store it or load it the same as there is for SQL/XML , but thanks for the heads up!